# JavaScript Calculating wrong

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to perform calculation using JavaScript. When user enter less than 10 pages in input (#page) the cost is 1. if he adds more than 10, each page costs .10. there are 2 options for checkbox, if he clicks first checkbox 10 is added and second checkbox 15 is added.

This is working when it is done in sequential steps. (input then clicking checkbox).

Ex: Input is : 9 (total: 1)
    click checkbox1 - duplicates (total : 11)
    click checkbox1 - laser (total: 26)

Now if i change the Input to 11, then the total becomes 1.10 - even if both the checkboxes are checked.. (expected result should be - 26.10)

I am not sure how to do this...can anyone help me out

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculation</title>
    <script>
        function calculate() {
            var pages=document.getElementById("page").value;

            if(pages <=10) {
                total.value=1;
            }
            if(pages >= 11) {
                var extra_pages= pages - 10;
                var new_total= extra_pages * .10;
                var new_total1= 1 + new_total;
                total.value= new_total1; 
            }
        }

        function checkbox1() {
            if(document.getElementById("ckbox1").checked === true) {
                var total1=document.getElementById("total").value;
                const add1 = 10;
                var check1 = +total1 + +add1;
                total.value=check1;
            }
            if(document.getElementById("ckbox1").checked === false) {
                var total1=document.getElementById("total").value;
                 const sub1 = 10;
                 var check2 = +total1 - +sub1;
                 total.value = check2;
            }
        }

        function checkbox2() {
            if(document.getElementById("ckbox2").checked === true) {
                var total1=document.getElementById("total").value;
                const add1 = 15;
                var check1 = +total1 + +add1;
                total.value=check1;  
            }
            if(document.getElementById("ckbox2").checked === false) {
                 var total1=document.getElementById("total").value;
                 const sub1 = 15;
                 var check2 = +total1 - +sub1;
                 total.value = check2;
            }
        }
</script>
<body>
     Enter a Number: <input type="text" id="page" value="1" oninput="calculate()">
    <br>
    <br><br><br><br>
       duplicates <input type="checkbox" id="ckbox1" onclick="checkbox1()">
    laser print: <input type="checkbox" id="ckbox2" onclick="checkbox2()"> <br><br>
    Total: <input type="text" id="total">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `calculate` didn't consider `duplicates` and `laser print` so they won't be included.

Comment: you have not defined total.value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `calculate` for all changes instead of creating each one for each `input`, which makes the calculation complex.

```js
// Get reference to inputs.
var page = document.getElementById("page");
var total = document.getElementById("total");
var dup = document.getElementById("ckbox1");
var laser = document.getElementById("ckbox2");

function calculate() {
  // To Number
  var pages = parseInt(page.value, 10);
  var value = 0;

  if (pages <= 10) {
    value = 1;
  } else {
    var extra_pages = pages - 10;
    var new_total = extra_pages * .10;
    var new_total1 = 1 + new_total;
    value = new_total1;
  }
  
  // Add 10 if dup is checked.
  if (dup.checked) {
    value += 10;
  }
  
  // Add 15 if laser is checked.
  // These can be moved out like
  // const laserVal = 15;
  // value += laserVal if you don't want magic number here.
  if (laser.checked) {
    value += 15;
  }
  
  // Truncate float.
  total.value = value.toFixed(1);
}
```

```html
Enter a Number:
<input type="text" id="page" value="1" oninput="calculate()">
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
duplicates:<input type="checkbox" id="ckbox1" onclick="calculate()">
laser print:<input type="checkbox" id="ckbox2" onclick="calculate()">
<br>
<br>Total:
<input type="text" id="total">
```

Comment: Open the dev tool, is there anything pop out on console? What's the detail about not working, change the pages won't change the total? Or click on checkbox will not get correct total? or even not adding the number?

Comment: can you check here please, i copy pasted the code and tried..but when i enter input..total is blank..also when i click checkbox..total field is blank.. - http://jsfiddle.net/vikrams/a3khbub1/

Comment: Note that jsfiddle default to wrap script part in an `onload` function, which makes it not accessible to your html part, make it to `no wrap - in <body>` would work, try http://jsfiddle.net/a3khbub1/1/ .

Comment: when i copy the code in HTML file..where should i paste the Javascript code..inside <head> or <body>....

Comment: At the end of the `body`, or in other words, right before the closing `</body>` would be better, it ensure that all existing html are rendered, so your javascript can access them.